# how do i remove an operating system (ubuntu)from my computer while still on another version of ubuntu?

Tags: system

I have Ubuntu 20.04, 21.04, and 22.04 on my computer. basically, I want to stay on 20.04 and delete the two other versions. because they are taking up too much space. how do I do that? do I do it using the app ''disks'' that is installed on Ubuntu 20.04 and how?? note that I want to remove the 2 other versions from Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi omg thank you so much. i was told about os-uninstaller but couldn't find any way to install it. this time it worked ! :D